# PWM with ADC - ATMega16

Tags: microcontroller, adc, pwm

I want to write code where I move the wiper of the potentiometer clockwise so it applies PWM on a pin, and when I move it counter-clockwise it applies PWM on another pin.

I could do it with Arduino, but I would like to do the same with ATMega16.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
short i = 0, i1;
short Reading[4];
short Reader(short ch){
    ADMUX = ch;
    ADMUX &= ~((1 << REFS0) | (1 << REFS1)|(1 << ADLAR)) ;
    ADCSRA |= (1<<ADSC);
    while(ADCSRA & (1<<ADSC))_delay_ms(5);
    return ADC;
}
ISR(ADC_vect){
    _delay_ms(100);
    ADCSRA &= ~(1 << ADSC);
    if(Reading[i] > 553){
        TCNT0 = 0; TCCR0 |= (1 << CS01);
        i1 = (i * 2 + 1); OCR0 = 255 * ((ADC - (1023 - 553))/553);
    }
    else if(Reading[i] < 435){
        TCNT0 = 0; TCCR0 |= (1 << CS01);
        i1 = (i * 2); OCR0 = 255 * ((453 - ADC)/453);
    }
    else{
        TCCR0 &= ~(1 << CS01);
    }
    if(i < 4) {Reading[i] = Reader(i); i++;}
    else {i = 0; Reading[i] = Reader(i); i++;}
    }
ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect){
    PORTD = (1 << i1);
    }
ISR(TIMER0_COMP_vect){
    PORTD = 0;
    }
int main(){
    DDRA = 0x00; DDRB = 0xff; DDRC = 0xff; DDRD = 0xff;
    PORTC = 0;
    Reader(0);
    sei();
    TIMSK |= (1 << TOIE0) | (1 << OCIE0);
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADEN)|(1 << ADATE)|(1 << ADPS0)|(1 << ADIE);
    SFIOR &= ~((1 << ADTS2)|(1 << ADTS1)|(1 << ADTS0) | (1 << 4)); // free running mode
    ADMUX &= ~((1 << REFS0) | (1 << REFS1)|(1 << ADLAR)) ;
    TCNT0 = 0;
    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

When I checked by adding some blinking LED code in the `ISR(ADC_vect)` it worked, which means the `ISR(ADC_vect)` is called but PWM doesn't work; though I could get it working on its own in another poject when I checked after I doubted that I didn't know how to get PWM applied, but it worked.

So please if anyone can detect a logical error here or any error please mention it, and if you can write a simple code for me to achieve this I will be more than grateful.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Update:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

short Reader(short);
int main(void){
    sei();
    SFIOR &= ~((1 << ADTS2)|(1 << ADTS1)|(1 << ADTS0) | (1 << 4)); // free running mode

    TIMSK |= (1 << OCIE0)|(1 << TOIE0);

    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADEN)|(1 << ADATE)|(1 << ADPS0)|(1 << ADIE) ;

    DDRC = 0xff; DDRB = 0xff;


    while(1){

       Reader(0);

        }

    return 0;
    }

ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect){
    PORTB = (1 << PB0);
    PORTC = (1 << PC0);
    }
ISR(TIMER0_COMP_vect){
  //  PORTC = 0x00;
    PORTC &= ~(1 << PC0);
    PORTB &= ~(1 << PB0);
    }

ISR(ADC_vect){
    if(ADC > 553){
        TCCR0 &= ~((1 << CS00)|(1 << CS01)|(1 << CS02));
        TCCR0 |= (1 << CS01)|(1 << CS00);
        OCR0 = 254 * ((ADC - 553)/(1023 - 553));
        //OCR0--;
        //_delay_ms(5);
        }
    else if(ADC < 453){
        TCCR0 &= ~((1 << CS00)|(1 << CS01)|(1 << CS02));
        TCCR0 |= (1 << CS01)|(1 << CS00);
        OCR0 = 254 * ((453 - ADC)/453);
        }
    else{PORTC = 0; PORTB = 0; TCCR0 &= ~((1 << CS00)|(1 << CS01)|(1 << CS02)); }
    }


short Reader(short ch){
    ADMUX = (ADMUX & 0xf8) | ch;
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC);
    while(ADCSRA & (1<<ADSC));
    if(ADC > 553){
        TCCR0 &= ~((1 << CS00)|(1 << CS01)|(1 << CS02));
        TCCR0 |= (1 << CS01)|(1 << CS00);
        OCR0 = 254 * ((ADC - 553)/(1023 - 553));
        }
    else if(ADC < 453){
        TCCR0 &= ~((1 << CS00)|(1 << CS01)|(1 << CS02));
        TCCR0 |= (1 << CS01)|(1 << CS00);
        OCR0 = 254 * ((453 - ADC)/453);
        }
    else{PORTC = 0; PORTB = 0; TCCR0 &= ~((1 << CS00)|(1 << CS01)|(1 << CS02)); }
    return ADC;
    }
```

It worked, but the LEDs light doesn't vary according to these two lines:

```
OCR0 = 254 * ((453 - ADC)/453);
```

and

```
OCR0 = 254 * ((ADC - 553)/(1023 - 553));
```

It is either one or zero.

How can I make it vary?

Comment: Please don't paste screengrabs of code but post the code and format it with the `{}` code button instead. That way we can read it and copy and edit in our answers.

Comment: I tried, but it took part of the code and added it in the code viewer while and the rest was written normally, not in code form. and it didn't look anything even close to code..

Comment: Paste it in, select all the code and press the `{}` code button.

Comment: I pressed that button and pasted the code where it says "enter your code here"

Comment: https://adnbr.co.uk/articles/adc-and-pwm-basics

Comment: G36, thank you, I will check that.

Answer (score -1):

As all the variables involved are integers, the result of the division `((453 - ADC)/453)` will be an integer as well. That means the result will be clipped to the nearest integer. When you expect the result being (e.g.) 0.2 it will be 0 instead, 1.8 will become 1. As a consequence, the whole term can only be 0 or 254.

You have to cast the divident as float, multiply this float with 254 and then cast it back to integer:

```
OCR0 = (uint_16t) 254 * ((453. - ADC)/453);
```

Note the "." behind 453, it makes 453 a float! Maybe you have to adapt `uint16_t` to the width of the corresponding compare register.

But apart from that there are several things in your code that aren't implemented well:

- why do you configure the timer in the ADC-ISR if the configuration doesn't actually change? You really should separate your code into an initialization and a main loop, just as you are used to from arduino.
- variables accessed in ISRs must be declared `volatile`
- you generally should enable interrupts at the end of initialization
- even though it's commented out: **NEVER** use a delay in an ISR!!!
- get rid of compiler warnings, I'm sure there are some ;)

Comment: No, integer division **does not** round, it truncates. `4 / 5` evaluates to zero.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, edited answer