# ADC with PWM glitch

Tags: microcontroller, avr

This code is for PWM works as long as the line `ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC);` is commented out. But when I remove the comment, it doesn't work.

I don't know why that happens. I want PWM and ADC to work together afterwards.

Thanks in advance. :)

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

short Reader(short);
int main(void){

    sei();
    SFIOR &= ~((1 << ADTS2)|(1 << ADTS1)|(1 << ADTS0) | (1 << 4)); // free running mode

    TIMSK |= (1 << OCIE0)|(1 << TOIE0);
    TCNT0 = 0; TCCR0 |= (1 << CS01); OCR0 = 127;

    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADEN)|(1 << ADATE)|(1 << ADPS2)|(1 << ADIE) ;

    DDRC = 0xff; DDRB = 0xff;
   // ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC);
    while(ADCSRA & (1<<ADSC));
    if (ADC > 512) {TCNT0 = 0; TCCR0 |= (1 << CS01); OCR0 = 0;}
    else {TCNT0 = 0; TCCR0 |= (1 << CS01); OCR0 = 127;}
    _delay_ms(5);

    while(1){

        }

    return 0;
    }

ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect){
    PORTB = (1 << PB0);
    PORTC = (1 << PC0);
    }
ISR(TIMER0_COMP_vect){
  //  PORTC = 0x00;
    PORTC &= ~(1 << PC0);
    PORTB &= ~(1 << PB0);
    OCR0--;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE Ahmed! Could you edit your question to: 1. Fix the formatting (use a code block for your source code), 2. Tell us what microcontroller you're using exactly, and 3. Clarify what "it doesn't work" means exactly in your case?

Comment: Ahmed - Regarding *marcelm's* 3 helpful questions. (1) I've fixed the formatting for you. I see that you also had problems correctly using the site to add code in your previous question. You'll need to learn that, but it was easier for me to fix it this time. (2) I *assume* this is related to your previous question "[PWM with ADC - ATMega16](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/422674)". I don't have time to carefully compare your 2 questions, but be careful - if you try to duplicate your questions, then one or both of them might be closed. (3) Please answer *marcelm's* question.

Comment: Marcelm, thank you..
the leds' weren't turning on, now they do turn on but without grades, without varying their illumination, either one or zero, I will update the question with the new code and the new poblem.

Comment: Marcelm, please check this one https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/422674/pwm-with-adc-atmega16
because I am not able to post the code blocks, I press the code and post where it says "post code here". but some of it is out of the block..
thankfully It was edited in the one I mentioned above by SamGibson, that is my problem now, thank you :) :)

Answer (score 2):

You enabled the ADC interrupt (ADIE) but have no ISR for it. Hence, if you start a conversion (ADSC), once the conversion finishes, the non existent ISR is called which usually automatically restarts the program. You get an endless loop of initializing, starting the ADC, and restarting the program. (Obviously, if you never start a conversion, the problem goes away.)

Disable (don't enable) the ADC interrupt:

```
ADCSRA |= (1 << ADEN)|(1 << ADATE)|(1 << ADPS2); // removed: |(1 << ADIE) ;
```

And don't enable auto-triggering (ADATE) if you don't need it.